# Word 2016: Heading 2 entries in Table of Contents are pixelated

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, microsoft-word-2016

I recently wrote a document using Word 2016 for Windows (7, 64-bit). I used a slightly modified version of the "Black & White (numbered)" Theme, where the primary changes are using Times New Roman in the various heading styles (e.g. Heading 1, Heading 2, etc.) instead of the default Cambria style, and the use of Times New Roman in the Normal body style.

Throughout the document, all the text appears properly smoothed and normal. Here is an enlarged version of the text from the body of the document, where "4 Experimental Techniques" is in the Heading 1 style (Times New Roman 18, bold, small caps, based on the Normal style) and "4.1 MAP 215-50 (Lab B50)" is in the Heading 2 style (Times new Roman 14, bold, small caps, based on the Normal style):
[image: Text as it appears in the body of the document]

Later, I then added a Table of Contents from the Reference tab, selecting Table of Contents, and adding "Automatic Table 2". Here is an elarged excerpt from the Table of Contents:

[image: Text as it appears in the Table of Contents]

Note that the entry for "4 Experimental Techniques" and "4.1.1 Description of Mass Spectrometer" (which, in the body text used Heading 3, Times New Roman 12, bold, based on the Normal style) are properly smoothed and high-quality in appearance, but the entry for "4.1 MAP 215-50 (Lab B50)" is pixelated and blurry.

Interestingly, the number "4.1" is smooth and clear, but the "MAP 215-50 (Lab B50)" as well as the dots and the corresponding page number off to the right (not shown) are pixelated.

This only happens for Table of Contents entries of text using the Heading 2 style in the body, and it happens for all such entries (e.g. 5.5, 5.6, etc. later in the Table of Contents). It only happens for certain fonts (I've tested a few, and it occurs with Times New Roman and Arial, but not Calibri), and then only for size 12. If the size is changed to, say 10 point, 12.5 point, or 14 point -- even if Times New Roman or Arial are used -- the problem does not appear.

Attempts to clear all formatting by selecting the blurry text and pressing Ctrl-Space cause the selected text to return to the Normal style (Times New Roman, 12, italic) for Table of Contents, but it is still pixelated at 12 point size.

I have two questions:

1. **What is causing this problem?**
2. **What can be done to fix it?**

As a temporary workaround, I can change the font size to 11.5 or 12.5 and it would likely go unnoticed by anyone looking at the document, but that doesn't actually address the problem.

Although I'd prefer not to post the document publicly, as it contains soon-to-be-published scientific research, I would be happy to make it available privately upon request. Alternatively, I could make a dummy document with the same styles that exhibits the same problem and make that available publicly. If additional screenshots or details of the configuration would be of assistance, please let me know what you'd like to see and I'd be happy to post more.

**Update:** a dummy document with the same styles, and which exhibits the same issues is available for download [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1f7l60gejocjqks/Dummy%20Document.docx?dl=0).

Comment: * Alternatively, I could make a dummy document with the same styles that exhibits the same problem and make that available publicly* Way to go...

Comment: @xenoid Sounds like a plan. I've updated the original question with a link to a dummy file (at the end of the question).

Comment: I am not seeing the problem in what you display.I've looked at the document and am still not seeing it. Note that how TOC entries appear is primarily controlled by the TOC styles. http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm

Answer (score 0):

There's an alternative way to get headings that are numbered like that.
It requires creating your own heading-style.
There's a widely-cited web-page on how to do that:

"How to create numbered headings or outline numbering in Word 2007 and Word 2010", by Shauna Kelly:
https://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html?p=1768

[Pic from Shauna's instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1AxK.png)

The process is complicated, and it involves creating heading and list styles.
I've done it three times over the last 10 years, and each time I've run into problems that took a while to fix.  Be sure to follow the instructions very carefully.

Also, the instructions are for Word 2010, so current Word versions may be a bit different.  The last time I used the instructions was in March 2021, with the current version of Word.

Additional discussion on using Shauna's instructions:
https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/17798-multi-level-list-hell.html

BTW:  The OP identifies "Black & White (numbered)" as being a Word Theme.  I think it is actually a Word Style Set.
https://www.dummies.com/article/technology/software/microsoft-products/general-microsoft/how-to-apply-styles-and-style-sets-in-word-2019-260335/
https://wordribbon.tips.net/T009689_Understanding_Style_Sets.html